# Graphics API Debugger error com.google.gapid.Server$GapisInitException

Tags: android, ios

I want to use Graphics API Debugger (GAPID) to analyse filter apps. I downloaded gapid-1.5.0 from https://github.com/google/gapid/releases.

When I then open gapid, it shows an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYq25.png):

```
com.google.gapid.Server$GapisInitException: Failed to connect to the graphics debugger
    at com.google.gapid.Server.connectToServer(Server.java:103)
    at com.google.gapid.Server.connect(Server.java:71)
    at com.google.gapid.Main$UI.startup(Main.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I make it work?